# How to write a triple differences model with fixed effects?

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

- I have a bunch of states $i$
- Some are treatment states and others are control states, where $T_i$ is 1 if treatment
- I believe the treatment effect differs for big states, where $B_i$ indicates if a state is big

So this is my model:
$$y_{it} = \gamma_i + \beta_1T_i + \beta_2P_t + \beta_3B_i + \beta_4T_iB_i + \beta_5 P_tB_i +  \alpha_1 T_iP_t + \alpha_2 T_iP_tB_i + \delta_{it}$$

Where $y_{it}$ is DV of state $i$ in year $t$, $T_i$ is 1 if treatment group and 0 otherwise, $P_i$ is 1 if post-treatment period and 0 otherwise, $B_i$ is 1 if big and 0 otherwise.

As of now, $T_i$ and $B_i$ would be dropped as it's colinear with the state fixed effect $\gamma_i$. So how do I write this such that nothing would be dropped?

Comment: First, is treatment *timing* well defined? Does it start at the same time for all treated units? Second, do both small and big states receive the treatment?

Comment: Hello Thomas, thanks for the clarifying questions. First, the timing is well defined. Both treatment and control states receive treatment at the same time. Second: Both control and treatment groups have some big and some small states.

Comment: Do you receive estimates for all your interactions terms? Also, care to share your output? It’s not necessary but is often helpful.